# Stata: expand by the number of variables

Tags: stata, expand

This relates to a general question I'm asking myself, how can I use the results of some code in another code if Stata does not create new objects except these clandestine locals and globals?

I would like to combine:

```
di c(k)
```

and:

```
expand
```

which I R I would simply do by writing something like `expand(di c(k))`. How does Stata take care of wrapped functions?

**edit:** I'm fine with using locals and globals but I don't always know how to call them into a function.

**edit2:** for everyone else who has trouble keeping track of 'clandestine' globals and locals: `macro list`

Comment: `expand` is a command, not a function.

Comment: `expand c(k)` will work fine. Not sure whether you really mean it, but there you go.

Comment: They're really not that "clandestine". Each `help` file reports the results being saved. See also `help saved results`, if you haven't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty you have in using `local`s, `global`s, `scalar`s, *saved results* is not obvious from your question. An example is:

```
clear
set more off

sysuse auto
keep rep78

summarize 

return list
expand r(max)
```

*Saved results* may disappear when other commands are issued, but you can save them into a `local`, for example, and use them later:

```
local rmax = r(max)
display `rmax'
expand `rmax'
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats a good summary. The expand c(k) also works, thank you Nick!